# Should i uninstall cordova and install phonegap if I want to use build.phonegap.com?

Tags: debugging, cordova, build

I started with Cordova 3.3.1-0.3.1 because I didn't know any better.  Everything installed by npm, etc.  Then i wasted much time trying to debug remotely using weinre, etc.

Moved onto build.phonegap.com, and linked my cordova git repo.  Build seems to work fine, but debugging still not working.  Slight progress in that the debugging client now connects to the target, but for some reason the app borks on the device:

Application Error
There was a network error.  (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

Now every time I open the app on the device I get:

Cordova API specs
bunch of links to tests none of which work.

One more note, Phonegap says my app is using an older version of Phonegap (2.9) and recommends upgrading to 3.0.  I'm using Cordova 3.3.  Should I uninstall cordova 3.3 and install phonegap?  Any issues to watch out for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to uninstall cordova to install phonegap, you can have both on your system.

If you created a project using cordova and want to use it in phonegap build, you have to modify the namespace in config.xml to have the phonegap specific parameters work. (for example gap:plugin for the plugins).

use `<widget id="com.app.package" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">`
instead of `<widget id="com.app.package" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">`

and in index.html, include phonegap.js instead of cordova.js.

About the error you have, I've seen that when the loading of index.html goes into a timeout.

It can be a javascript taking too long or you checked debug in phonegap build but the device can't access the weinre server before the timeout.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, they were helpful, but still no success.  Here's what's happening:

... I cleaned up the XML, added platforms/ and plugins/ to the gitignore, cleaned up the git repo.  Turned OFF debugging.
...Still getting the index.html error, which is weird because index.html is supposed to be local to the device.  
...Then noticed that no plugins are recognized by Phonegap's build service.  Added to the XML as in Phonegap build docs.  Still no plugins recognized, builds still completely borked.  No access to index.html. Any thoughts?

Comment: So, another weird thing/update... I kept mashing the app button and voila!  It worked... even saw my remote debugging target light up for a moment (before the app fired the camera device and lost debugging for the session).  Disabled the camera firing (the primary purpose of my app) and was able to narrow down my javascript problem on the device to the fact that the jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js file doesn't seem to be loading.  It is included in my repo, works on localhost and adb emulators, but is borking on the android device.

Comment: Try to replace cordova.js with phonegap.js in index.html if not already done. You can edit the question with config.xml.

Comment: Haven't gotten to the bottom of everything, but I did find that the mobile device was borking on an extra forward slash at the beginning of the jquery color library path, whereas the other browsers were not.  Thank you remote debugging!  And thanks for the tips.  Will mark as answered.  (Also, the version discrepancy was a result of a configuration setting in Phongap Build. Set to 3.3 and no more warnings.)

Comment: Question.  Can I have both cordova.js and phonegap.js in my index.html?  I'd like to be able to use both for having one repo for Phonegap and local builds (which include plugins at the moment).

Comment: phonegap.js automatically includes cordova.js (uses require). If you use phonegap cli, you can build locally. When you add plugins you just have to use `phonegap plugin add` and add a gap:plugin line in config.xml. If at some point you need to use phonegap build for a project, I suggest you don't use cordova at all for that project and do everything with phonegap.

Comment: OK, will change to phonegap.js for sure and will probably migrate to phonegap entirely.  Can I just install phonegap with npm tools over the top of cordova or ???  Thanks.

Comment: Argh!  Adding phonegap.js did not fix the problem.  Still no plugins.  Installing phonegap in its entirety (over the top of cordova) and will build a new project and migrate the git repo one more time.

Comment: have you added the gap:plugin lines in config.xml to add the plugins? (for ex `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />`) About the phonegap version message you have, check if you have a `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.1.0" />` tag in config.xml. If not, set the version in the Settings tab on the phonegap build site.

Comment: Yep, I did all those things, still not seeing any plugins loading either on the build site or in the actual app.  Thanks for your continued effort, regardless.  You've been trying to help me over here, where you can see more of my code/config: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761618/plugins-not-working-in-phonegap-using-build-phonegap-com-no-navigator-device-ob)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I zipped up the whole project folder.  I tried again with just www folder zipped and it worked.