# Plugins not working in Phonegap using build.phonegap.com, no navigator.device object (undefined)

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, build, device

So I'm having a lot of difficult with build.phonegap.com workflow.  Using Cordova 3.3 and a Droid Razr Maxx.  If I build locally, plugins work in emulator.  In Phonegap build (on device), the javascript is working well but the plugins are totally borked.    I have added the plugin code to my config.xml, but they don't show up in my project on build.phonegap.com.  Using remote debugging, I have no navigator.device object, even after manually firing the deviceready callback with success.  Therefore no calls to plugins work.

config.xml:

> S,T,L.
>       
>           Something great.
>       
>       
>           Marc

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
```

Some code, including my device ready:

```
    // device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log('device ready');
    $('#group1').hide();
    $('.ui-btn').hide();
    $('#group2').hide();
    captureImage();
}

function checkboxHandler(callback) {
  console.log(callback.id + " clicked, new value = " + callback.checked);
        if (callback.checked) {
            $('.' + callback.id).show();
            console.log('showing ' + callback.id);
        } else {
            $('.' + callback.id).hide();
        }
}

function addTemplateItems (template) {


  // SNIP SNIP

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  addTemplateItems(tagTemplate);

  $(document).delegate('.ui-page', "swipeleft", function(){
      var $nextPage = $(this).next('[data-role="page"]');
      var $prevPage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
      console.log("binding to swipe-left on "+$(this).attr('id') );
      // swipe using id of next page if exists
      if ($nextPage.length > 0) {
          $.mobile.changePage($nextPage, { transition: 'slide' });
      } else {
          var message = 'tagged!';

          // save tags here

          flashNotify(message);
          console.log('fire event!');
          $('#flashNotification').promise().done(function () {
            $('#group1').hide();
            $('#group2').hide();
            $('.ui-btn').hide();
            addTemplateItems(tagTemplate);
            $.mobile.changePage($prevPage, { transition: 'none' });
            captureImage();
          }); 
      }
  }).delegate('.ui-page', "swiperight", function(){
      var $prevPage = $(this).prev('[data-role="page"]');
      console.log("binding to swipe-left on "+$(this).attr('id') );
      // swipe using id of next page if exists
      if ($prevPage .length > 0) {
          $.mobile.changePage($prevPage, { transition: 'slide', reverse : true });
      } else {
          alert('no backy backy!');
      }
  });

});


document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: you created the project with cordova cli and are trying to use the config.xml generated with cordova in phonegap build? If yes, check my answer there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138074/phonegap-build-config-xml-malformed

Comment: Oops, sorry, that's what happens when you come on stack overflow too late at night...

Comment: Actually it seems that everything I told you (which was based on my knowledge of phonegap cli from 3.0 to 3.2) may be wrong for 3.3. I suggest you read http://devgirl.org/2014/02/10/3-cordova-cli-changes/ (haven't had time to read it yet but I think it may explain many things)

Comment: So I read the blog entry and though there are some changes in various CLI commands, there don't seem to be any changes in the way plugins are referenced, unless I missed something.  I think what I'm going to do is create a whole new project with the Phonegap CLI and start from scratch, cope the html/js in and see what happens.